# Python - Uploading files with Hebrew filenames in Request.Post

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, seafile-server

I'm trying to upload files to [seafile server API](https://manual.seafile.com/develop/web_api_v2.1.html#upload-file-1).

Uploading files with Hebrew filenames return an error from the server when using `requests.post`.
Request on fiddler-

> 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name:"file";
>   filename*=utf-8''b%27%5C.....'

Uploading files with Hebrew filenames manually succeed.

Request on fiddler-

> 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name:"file"; filename="בדיקה.docx"
>   Content-Type:
>   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"

Python code:

```
import requests


response = requests.post(
    upload_link, data={'filename': 'בדיקה.doc', 'parent_dir': '/'},
    files={'file': open('c:/Users/xiez/בדיקה.doc', 'rb')},
    headers={'Authorization': 'Token {token}'. format(token=token)}
)
```

Server response:

> 502 Bad Gateway The proxy server received an invalid response from an
>   upstream server

Comment: Are you getting any more details than 502?

Comment: no, but the issue is encoding on the post filename, this is the only diff between the requests

Comment: What version of python are you using? You may need to specify that the filename is `unicode`, if using Python 2